# Don't see the option to convert Stateful into stateless widget

Tags: flutter, android-studio

[image: Stateless]
When I click on stateless widgets name, is shows a bulb. By clicking on it, I get an option to convert into stateful widget.
But when I want to convert a stateful into a stateless, I can't find the bulb. I tried Alt+Enter but no luck.[image: Stateful]

Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2
[image: Flutter Doctor]

Comment: most likely you have `initState` method or similar `State` method that prevents refactoring

Comment: I tried with default counter app. Same issue found.

Comment: tried a stateful widget that has *only* `build` method and nothing else?

Comment: Yes. Tried restart, re-install, invalidate cache, plugin re-install, shortcut keys; but no luck. If you are not facing the issue please share your flutter sdk version, android studio version, flutter and dart plugin version.

Answer (score 1):

In vs code you can convert it by doing the ( ctrl+ . ) and can convert it to

and if your are using the setstate try to magange that

Comment: Ctrl+. is not working. Alt+Enter is working on Stateless, no luck on Stateful

Answer (score 0):

Remove the State class that's associated with the stateful widget.
Remove any state-related methods such as createState() and the state lifecycle methods (initState(), build(), etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using an outdated version of the [Flutter plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter). In previous versions, it is only possible to convert from `StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget`. Upgrade your Flutter plugin to the latest version to enable converting from `StatefulWidget` to `StatelessWidget`.

You can check/update plugins by going to `File > Settings > Plugins`.

[image: Plugins setting screenshot]

Now you'll have the option to convert to `StatelessWidget`:

[image: Option screenshot]

Comment: My current flutter plugin version is 77.2.1; what is yours?

Comment: I use 77.1.1. You seem to be using a newer version, but I'm not sure why the option is not available on yours. Maybe you should try making a fresh new `StatelessWidget`, convert it to `StatefulWidget`, and see if there's the option to convert back to `StatelessWidget`. I've included the screenshot of mine showing the option

Comment: Also what's your Flutter & Dart version? (not the plugin; you might want to include your `flutter doctor` output in the post)

Comment: Added flutter doctor output.

Comment: Try to create a new project and see if it's showing. I suspect the sdk version set in the pubspec affect the Dart plugin. I use `sdk: '>=3.1.5 <4.0.0'` in my project so the option is available to me

Comment: Tried. The bulb showes up, but the option for turning into stateless widget was not there.